# plot.new has not been called yet error when it worked previously

Tags: r, lattice

Simple code running the following:

```
library(lattice)
histogram(data$tenure, breaks = 10, main = 'Distribution - Tenure', xlab = 'tenure')
lines(density(data$tenure))
```

yet I receive the error message ...plot.new has not been called yet. This exact same code worked last night, but when I re-ran this morning, i started getting the error message. how to fix?

I have a nearly identical example from a training that worked at the time, but is now giving the same message:

```
birth <- read.csv("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/birth-rate.csv")
birth2008 <- birth$X2008[!is.na(birth$X2008)]
d2008 <- density(birth2008)
library(lattice)
histogram(birth$X2008, breaks=10)
lines(d2008)
```

Comment: `lattice::histogram` and `graphics::lines` are built on two different graphics systems. Did the training define a new function called `lines`?

Comment: Nope, but the weird thing is now it is working. I can get it to work once, but then I have to run plot(density(data$tenure)) in between each block (i am making multiple charts, one for data$tenure, one for data$MonthlyCharges, etc: png('tenuredist.png)
histogram(data$tenure, breaks = 10, main = 'Distribution - Tenure', xlab = 'tenure')
lines(density(data$tenure))
dev.off()

Comment: but that won't draw anything on your `histogram`. It works because you initiated a new device using base graphics (`plot(density(...))`) so your `lines` are drawn on that plot, not the histogram

Comment: I figure it has something to do with initiating a new one, but when I run this sequentially, it adds the lines to the histogram that replaced the base density plot:    plot(density(data$tenure))

png('tenuredist.png)
histogram(data$tenure, breaks = 10, main = 'Distribution - Tenure', xlab = 'tenure')
lines(density(data$tenure))
dev.off()

plot(density(data$tenure))

png('MCdist.png')
histogram(data$MonthlyCharges, breaks = 10, main = 'Distribution - MonthlyCharges', xlab = 'MonthlyCharges')
lines(density(data$MonthlyCharges))
dev.off()